# Find the first matching document from an array of ids

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have the following documents in one collection "packs":

```
{ _id: "animals"}
{ _id: "sillyanimals", extends: ["animals"] }
```

And these documents another collection "things":

```
{ _id: 1, thing: "dog", pack: "animals", bark: true, silly: false}
{ _id: 2, thing: "cat", pack: "animals", bark: false, silly: false }
{ _id: 3, thing: "dog", pack: "sillyanimals", silly: true }
```

How could I get the "cat" from the pack "sillyanimals" with a single query? It should return id _2, because sillyanimals extends animals.

Also, when I search for a "dog" in the "sillyanimals" pack, how would I get a result that combines id _1 and id _3 with a single query? The properties of _3 should take precedence and override the properties of _1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this query for "cat":

```
db.getCollection('packs').aggregate([
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: 'things',
       localField: 'extends',
       foreignField: 'pack',
       as: "inherited"
     }
}
,{$unwind:"$inherited"}
,{$match:{"inherited.thing":"cat"}}    //1)Set "dog"
,
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: 'things',
       localField: '_id',
       foreignField: 'pack',
       as: "content1"
     }
}
,{$unwind:"$content1"}

,{
         $project:
           {

             properties:
               {

                   $cond: {
                        if: {
                          $eq: ['$content1.thing', "cat"]   //2)set dog
                        },
                        then: "$content1",
                        else: "$inherited",
                      }
               }
           }
}

])
```

If you search "dog", change the parameters in 1) and 2)